# how to set up .app domain in heroku (https is mandatory)

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, dns

I am trying to set up my domain (mivoto.app) but I am having troubles, the domains .app [enforces https with ssl by default](https://get.app/#benefits), and I have read the documentation and some tutorials on internet, but none covers this specific case. I am trying to use your Automated Certificate Management but it seems it doesn't work.

I think I have set up the configuration in the DNS properly, but I have all this time this error:

[image]

I share with you some screenshots, where you can see how the dns is set up (the provider is google domain)

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like your DNS redirects `mivoto.app` to `https://www.mivoto.app`, and your `www` subdomain has a CNAME that looks right, but you're trying to use `mivoto.app` on Heroku. Replace `mivoto.app` with `www.mivoto.app` on Heroku and try setting up ACM again.

Comment: .APP is not a specific case. It uses HSTS, true, like many other domains/TLDs. But that just means you need a certificate and your website needs to be reachable over HTTPS. That part is not specific to .APP it is the same for any website under any name.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Chris was right, that was the actual problem, I quote here his answer

> It looks like your DNS redirects mivoto.app to https://www.mivoto.app,
>   and your www subdomain has a CNAME that looks right, but you're trying
>   to use mivoto.app on Heroku. Replace mivoto.app with www.mivoto.app on
>   Heroku and try setting up ACM again.